# SQL Aggreate Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, aggregate

I have table which list a number of cases and assigned primary and secondary technicians.  What I am trying to accomplish is to aggregate the number of cases a technician has worked as a primary and secondary tech.  Should look something like this...

```
Technician     Primary     Secondary
John             4              3
Stacy            3              1
Michael          5              3
```

The table that I am pulling that data from looks like this:

```
CaseID, PrimaryTech, SecondaryTech, DOS
```

In the past I have used something like this, but now my superiors are asking for the number of secondary cases as well...

```
SELECT PrimaryTech, COUNT(CaseID) as Total
GROUP BY PrimaryTech
```

I've done a bit of searching, but cant seem to find the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group two subqueries together with a FULL JOIN as demonstrated in this [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0db6a/1).

```
SELECT Technician = COALESCE(pri.Technician, sec.Technician)
    , PrimaryTech
    , SecondaryTech
FROM 
    (SELECT Technician = PrimaryTech
        , PrimaryTech = COUNT(*)
    FROM Cases
    WHERE PrimaryTech IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY PrimaryTech) pri
FULL JOIN
    (SELECT Technician = SecondaryTech
        , SecondaryTech = COUNT(*)
    FROM Cases
    WHERE SecondaryTech IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY SecondaryTech) sec
    ON pri.Technician = sec.Technician
ORDER By Technician;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Tech, 
       sum(case when IsPrimary = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as PrimaryCount,
       sum(case when IsPrimary = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as SecondaryCount
from
(
  SELECT SecondaryTech as Tech, 0 as IsPrimary
  FROM your_table
  union all
  SELECT PrimaryTech as Tech, 1 as IsPrimary
  FROM your_table
) x
GROUP BY Tech
```

Comment: thank you for the prompt response and the clean up.  The issue is that the Primary and Secondary tech fields are varchar's.  So I want to group by the Primary tech field then sum the number of rows in which they fall under the secondary tech field...

Comment: That's what this query does.

Comment: This approach will return a NULL technician if there is a primary and no secondary.  This can be avoided by adding WHERE PrimaryTech/SecondaryTech IS NOT NULL to there subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.NAME, B.NAME) AS NAME, CASE WHEN A.CASES IS NOT NULL THEN A.CASES ELSE 0 END AS PRIMARY_CASES,
CASE WHEN B.CASES IS NOT NULL THEN B.CASES ELSE 0 END AS SECONDARY_CASES
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CASES, PRIMARYTECH AS NAME FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY PRIMARYTECH
) AS A
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CASES, SECONDARYTECH AS NAME FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY SECONDARYTECH
) AS B
ON A.NAME = B.NAME
```